# Add leading zeroes in CSS counter style class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a particular `<p>` style class (`p.wp` for example) and I need it to increment from `1 - n` *throughout a series of HTML pages*.

The trick is that the complete number needs to contain 4 digits: 0001 through 0117, specifically.

```css
#start_wp {counter-reset: WP 0;}

p.wp{}

p.wp:before{
counter-increment: WP 1;
content: "WP 000" counter(WP, decimal)  ':';}
```

```html
<body id="start_wp">
<p class="wp">This is a work package</p>
<p class="wp">This is a work package</p>
</body>
```

I can set a number easily through auto-number for 0001-0009 with the use of `before:`. But then I think I'd have to create 2 others classes for 00nn and 0nnn. But there has to be a way via JavaScript or jQuery to do auto-numbering.

My challenges are:

- Where do I put a `counter-reset` if I want numbering to continue across all pages.
- Could I set it via an ID?

  - Would I add the jQuery or JS to every page that's affected by the counter?

While I've got the CSS thing relatively understood - JS and jQuery are a mystery to me. I'd love some guidance.

Update:

I have scavenged other code and have come up with this:

```
   function LeadingZeros (){
  var num = 4;
  if num = (num < 10)
      result = ("000" + num);

  if num = (num < 100)
      result = ("00" + num);

  if num = (num < 1000)
      result = ("0" + num);
}
```

BUT, I have no idea

- If this is even on the right track
- If it is close (or even moving in the right direction), what I do after this.

Thoughts?

Comment: If JavaScript is a mystery to you, then any implementation suggested here won't help your understanding. You should learn the language and attempt a solution yourself. If you can't get it to work, only then should you ask for help here by including your code. That's the best way to receive meaningful community help.

Comment: Thanks, Brett. That was really helpful. What I meant is that I can code CSS without a problem - but writing JavaScript and jQuery, not so much.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the leading zeros bit with CSS by setting a `counter-style`— `counter(counter, <counter-style>)`. From [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/numbering-in-style/):

> ... the numbers don't have to be decimals. They can be anything that `list-style-type` can be...

In this case, I think what you're looking for is `content: counter(my-counter, decimal-leading-zero)`. And check out the rest of that article: it should get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Is there a way to set the number of leading zeros? What about defining the total digit of the counter? Something like `fprintf()`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done, depending on the browser. (Experimental api)

```
    @counter-style pad-4 {
        system: numeric;
        symbols: "0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9";
        pad: 4 "0";
    }
```

And then

```
    ol { 
      list-style-type: pad-4;           
     }
```

or

```
    .class::after {
        content: "." counter(output-decimal, pad-4);
    }
```